# Why Query is returning empty array?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, wpdb, table

I am trying to execute a query using the below code but I'm getting empty array in **var_dump**.

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$slug = $post->post_name;

$course = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_name = $slug" );
var_dump($course);exit; //
```

If I run the same query in **PHPMyAdmin** it returns 2 records:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_name = "course-1"; // this returns 2 records
```

I also vardump `$slug = $post->post_name;` in code and it is return the below

```
string(8) "course-1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to wrap $slug in quotes

```
$course = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_name = '$slug'" );
```

Comment: If you're using `$wpdb`, it's best to get in the habit of using [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) too. In this case, `$course = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = %s', $slug ) );`